# Laravel: get checkbox value from html table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a blade page with a html table where any row has a checkbox, all these rows have a key value. I need all these checkbox values and update a table. At the moment I have this solution, but it seems not the best choice.

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th >ARRIVED</th>
      <th >Cron.</th>
      <th >NAME</th>
    </tr>   
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{$counter=1}}
    @foreach($data as $row)
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="arrived_yes_no_{{$counter}}"></td>
        <td>{{$row->Crono}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->Name}}</td>
      </tr>
      {{$counter++}}
    @endforeach 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I will rename any checkbox with the `_$counter` suffix so when I send via post all the page content I can (I hope) retrive all the checkbox values.

Is there a better option?

Comment: Although I can't answer your question I do have an idea to improve your code: instead of `name="arrived_yes_no_{{$counter}}"`  you can consider using an array: `name="arrived_yes_no[]`. The checks in your PHP code will need to be adapted in order for this to work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Virginia has the right idea. Changing the checkbox names to array syntax keyed by the ID of the row will make it much easier to work with server side.

```
// checkbox names
name="arrived_yes_no[{{ $row->id }}]"
```